# hosting provider web server blocks certain url string by using mod security

Tags: mod-security

I have a blog which has a post with the following as url

> /blog/insert-into-tablea-select-fields-from-tableb-for-specific-values-only/

This was working well until recently.

I got a different HTTP Status like 412 Precondition Failed which is not caused by request i am sure of it. They just want to send a status code.

All other urls are working except this.

When i questioned them they said that they have added mod security and that would have prevented. And they removed mod security for my user profile yesterday and the page is loading well.

The same has been done for mysql... certain queries are failing and they answered that mod security would have prevented it.

Besides, before three or four months the hosting company has hosted with softlayer and not it is a different server in India.

My questions are

1. do other servers use mod security to filter vulnerable queries and requests?
2. where to get a list of vulnerable requests and sql queries? so that i can make sure that my queries and requests pass mod security instead of getting blocked.
3. Is it possible for the server to remove or lower the restriction used mod security? is so then i can suggest them.

???

Comment: You really need to talk to **your provider** about this -- As you are not the system administrator there's nothing *you* can do, and nothing *we* can advise you other than "Talk to your provider"

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm working at a bank, and we're using mod_security.
2. There's a standard ruleset, but your provider may have made some changes to it, so it'ds best to ask them for their ruleset. (See below.)
3. mod_security is configurable, so it's possible for your provider to alter what restrictions are applied to your server. Of course, that doesn't mean that they're actually willing to do so, since it'll increase their workload to keep several different rulesets up to date.

There's more information, including about the core ruleset, at [the modsecurity website](http://www.modsecurity.org)